# filtering on keys produced in map_agg function - Trino

Tags: sql, presto, trino

looking for a good solution to filter on keys being used in the mapp_agg function in the query below.

I am trying to filter the key column to reduce the size of the map to only the columns I am looking to create, however when running this I get a key not present error. If I dont use an IN but rather an OR then it work but that impact performance as I add additional columns

```
SELECT 
id,
metric_id,
kv['uni Amount'] as uni_amt,
kv['mrt Amount'] as mrt_amt
FROM 
id,
metric_id,
map_agg(
        key,
        value
      ) kv
from table
where key in ('uni Amount', 'mrt Amount')
group by 
id,
metric_id)
```

I tried to use map_filter as well but couldn't get it working

```
SELECT 
id,
metric_id,
kv['uni Amount'] as uni_amt,
kv['mrt Amount'] as mrt_amt
FROM 
id,
metric_id,
map_filter(map_agg(
        key,
        value
      ), (k,v) k -> k in ('uni Amount', 'mrt Amount')
from table
group by 
id,
metric_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a minor syntax mistake/type, [`map_filter`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_filter) requires a second parameter in form of function with two arguments (key and value) and resulting in bool which can be written in anonymous/lambda/arrow form which is can be found in a lot of languages. Try changing `(k,v) k -> k in ('uni Amount', 'mrt Amount')` to `(k,v) -> k in ('uni Amount', 'mrt Amount')` (`k` and `v` are key and value parameters of the function) and add missing parenthesis:

```sql
-- ...
map_filter(
    map_agg(key, value)
    , (k,v) -> k in ('uni Amount', 'mrt Amount'))
-- ...
```

> however when running this I get a key not present error

You can use [`element_at`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#element_at) instead of indexer access which requires key to be present:

> `element_at(map(K, V), key) → V` Returns value for given key, or NULL if the key is not contained in the map.

Comment: hello, I made the suggested changes but unfortunately no luck. I am getting a "Key not present in map" error but the keys are definitely present in the dataset I am querying. I have a feeling it because map_filter is evaluating to True/False so wrapping it around map_agg might not work.

Comment: @YaRrrrrMatey 1) then you need to provide some sample data and desired output, i.e. a [mre] 2) _"I have a feeling"_ - either I have not understood you or you feeling is wrong, `map_filter` will filter not matching keys but it will not guarantee that row actually has both values (or any if that matters), not sure how `OR` does make the first query work (seems strange TBH). Please see small update to the answer.